# How to Unbind/Stop onMouseOut event if form fields have focus, in hoverIntent jQuery plugin?

Tags: jquery, hover, hoverintent

I'm using the jQuery plugin [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) to expand/shorten a div which has a form in it. As you can see below, the form is shown, when the div is tall.

How can I prevent the onMouseOut/makeShort from firing if any of the form fields have focus?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var config = {    
         over: makeTall, // function = onMouseOver callback (REQUIRED)    
         timeout: 650, // number = milliseconds delay before onMouseOut    
         out: makeShort // function = onMouseOut callback (REQUIRED)   
    };

    $("#mydiv").hoverIntent( config );

    function makeTall(){ 
            $(this).css({"height":100});
            $("#myForm").show('fast');
    }

    function makeShort(){
            $("#myForm").hide('fast');
            $(this).css({"height":50});
    }

});
```

I'm also open to suggestion if there is another more robust plugin for hover events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check for active elements:

```
function makeTall(){ 
    $(this).css({"height":100});
    $("#myForm").show('fast');
}

function makeShort(){
    if (!$("#myForm").find(':focus').length) {
        $("#myForm").hide('fast');
        $(this).css({"height":50});
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems right except it sounds like he doesn't want to apply the check to makeTall() only makeShort().

Comment: The OP was asking how to prevent those two functions from firing if the form had focused fields. I don't recall him saying anything about not modifying those functions.

Comment: "How can I prevent the onMouseOut/makeShort from firing..." He is only talking about the mouseout, which is the makeShort function.

Comment: I know. When the mouse moves out, the `<div>` will jerk (the `.css()` function doesn't animate), which isn't something I'd like to happen if I were building this script.

Comment: @Blender
makeShort is halted even when there is not focus at all. Let me post on jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use jQuery's [mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) and [mouseenter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter) methods.

> The mouseleave event differs from mouseout in the way it handles event bubbling. If mouseout were used in this example, then when the mouse pointer moved out of the Inner element, the handler would be triggered. This is usually undesirable behavior. The mouseleave event, on the other hand, only triggers its handler when the mouse leaves the element it is bound to, not a descendant. So in this example, the handler is triggered when the mouse leaves the Outer element, but not the Inner element.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/TeYNw/2/

Comment: On Google Chrome, nothing changes in the behavior if I select the textbox.

Comment: @Soliah, I'm using the plugin because it does some background stuff to check if the user really wants to hover or is just passing over the element.